# Move guards to database in ZF2 application with ZfcRbac

Tags: zend-framework2, rbac, zfc-rbac

I am using [`ZfcRbac`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac) for managing role-based access control for my ZF2 application. Currently I am controlling the access by updating the `guards` in `zfc_rbac.global.php` file in following way.

```
     'guards' => [
         'ZfcRbac\Guard\RouteGuard' => [
             'p304'             => ['*'],
             'zfcuser/logout'   => ['*'],
             'home'             => ['admin', 'engineer', 'user'],
             'application*'     => ['admin'],
             'AppUser*'         => ['admin'],
             'Clients*'         => ['admin', 'engineer', 'user'],
             'zfcadmin*'        => ['admin'],
             'zfcuser'          => ['admin', 'engineer', 'user'],
             'zfcuser/login'    => ['guest'],
         ]
     ],
```

I am struggling to find a way to move it to Database. Hope any one can help me to move this access control definition to database.

Comment: You could easily extend one of the factories, say `ZfcRbac\Factory\ModuleOptionsFactory.php` and add the permissions/roles to the module configuration dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Doctrine as ORM there is already a [documentation in ZfcRbac](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/docs/07.%20Cookbook.md#using-zfcrbac-with-doctrine-orm) on how to implement this.